# Hotmail SMTP cache?

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

So this is an odd one ...

Does Hotmail in anyway resolve and cache information for MX records or A records for individual email addresses?

For Example:
I setup a personal test bed mail server and tried sending from my own mail server to hotmail.  It Works...great!  Let's try receiving, Nope doesn't work.  Used dig and found out my own Name Servers were set to the wrong IP. Changed and tested... Still not working.  Tried an alternative hotmail account, checked webmail ... this account seems to work fine as does icloud etc... 12 hours later the hotmail account that wasn't working contains 10 emails about delay.  Checked 24 hours later and they started to appear in my personal inbox? eh?

Why would one hotmail address be able to send fine but not the other... Would this be hotmail delaying email because it couldn't initially find DNS, queued email for spam issues?

Anyone had similar issues or can enlighten me, forgive my ignorance.

Comment: What is the TTL on the MX record?

Comment: 14400 - I believe thats 4 hours. Would it be down to just that ttl?

Comment: Was the MX record also changed when you changed name servers?

Comment: @joeqwerty You know what I think it may have actually.  Starting to make sense now. However with a 4 hour TTL seems a long time for it to expire.

Comment: Can you post the full header of delayed Hotmail email? Especially in *Received* header section